# Performance Issues with sqlite joins

Tags: join, sqlite, database-performance

I've been working on building a database structure, when I ran into a problem. I have 3 tables A,B,C. Tables B and C have a 1-1 relationship while Tables A and B have a many-1 relationship. I attempted to run the following query.

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id = B.id
INNER JOIN C ON B.id = C.B_id
LIMIT 0,40
```

The query never completed, and the program ran for several seconds before not responding. Seeing as this query will need to return thousands of records, I was rather distraught that it didn't work limited to only 40 records. I then remembered that indices existed, so I created an index on all of the join criteria. I created one for A.B_id,B.id, and C.B_id. The result was a query that worked. It worked after I removed the limit clause as well, so I proceeded to the next query.

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id = B.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.id = C.B_id
LIMIT 0,40
```

Note that the only difference is the second join is now a left outer join. I though that since the keys are all the same, the index should still speed this one up. I was incorrect, as the query above completed, but was rather slow. I removed the limit clause, and the query didn't complete. I removed the indices that I added previously and tried the limited statement again. It ran in the same time.

The problem ended up being that without indices, the `INNER JOIN` did not work at all and the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` worked only when limited, though it was also slow. With the indices, the `INNER JOIN` successfully completed as quickly as I need it to be, but the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` continued to work about the same.

- Table A has 200,000 records
- Table B has 50,000 records
- Table C has 10,000 records
- The LEFT OUTER JOIN query above should produce 40,000 records

Does anyone know a way to speed this up? Am I missing an index or something that would increase the performance of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

---

As requested, here are the outputs for explain query plan:

For the two INNER JOINS:

1. "0" "0" "2" "SCAN TABLE C USING COVERING INDEX c.bid (~1000000 rows)"
2. "0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE B USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)"
3. "0" "2" "0" "SEARCH TABLE A USING COVERING INDEX a.bid (B_id=?) (~10 rows)"

For the INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN:

1. "0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE A USING COVERING INDEX a.bid (~1000000 rows)"
2. "0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE B USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)"
3. "0" "2" "2" "SCAN TABLE C USING COVERING INDEX c.bid (~100000 rows)"

Comment: These indexes should be enough (and the one on `A.B_id` is superfluous). What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for these queries?

Comment: Thanks for the command. I have never seen that before. I added the output of running the explain query plan on my statements. The OUTER JOIN seems to be causing an entire table scan instead of a search.

Comment: Please show the table definitions.

Comment: Well, I feel like a complete idiot. Thank you for your help CL. The column C.B_id was of type `TEXT` as opposed to `INTEGER` as it should. I can't believe I missed that. Why this effects the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and not the `INNER JOIN` is still shocking.

Comment: Performing multiple INNER JOIN with SQLLite is a VERY bad idea as this DB system is clearly not good with that. I've tried a query with 10 INNER JOIN on a big table with MariaDB and it take less than one second while in SQL Lite it last about 3 minutes. Search "sql lite inner join speed" on Google and you' ll see the problem. :/